# Change resolution of extracted frame in Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, video, frame, h.264

I have an H.264 video stream and I need to extract frames from it. However when I extract the frames,the quality is really poor since I need to perform color segmentation!I want to know how can i extract the frame and convert it to B G R so as to have a better quality picture.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(){
    VideoCapture capture("1.dv4");
    if(!capture.isOpened())
        return 1;

    double rate=capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);

    bool stop(false);

    Mat frame;
    namedWindow("Extracted Frame",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);

    cout <<"Rate is="<<rate;

    int delay=1000/rate;

    while(!stop){
        if(!capture.read(frame))
            break;

            imshow("Extracted Frame",frame);
            imwrite("C:/Users/DELL/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/VideoFrameCapture/VideoFrameCapture/frame.jpg",frame);

        if(waitKey(delay)>=0)
            stop=true;
    }
    capture.release();
    waitKey(0);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you have so far that is extracting the poor quality fram

Comment: Here is the code http://pastebin.com/s2MgaX89

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have opened the VideoCapture, add this:

```
 capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, 1);
```

Comment: has anyone found a solution please?

Comment: i made a mistake..yes it works..but when doing so,does it change its resolution or does it stay the same?because the resolution is still poor(352x288)..Can the resolution be increased?

Comment: Did you try viewing the dv4 file in some viewer to check what it should look like? Have you tried e.g. `capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)` and `capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)`?

Comment: i added those 2 lines like that : double rate= capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
 capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, 1);
 capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280);
 capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720); When I view the image,its dimensions are still the same

Comment: has anyone found a solution please?